# R, finding installed packages

Tags: r, package, subset

I have used `installed.packages()` to see installed packages in R. And I want to extract two columns from the output, "Packages" and "Version" by using `installed.packages()[c("Package","Version")]` but it does not show what I expect. But if I put a "," just before "Package" (`installed.packages()[,c("Package","Version")])` it works! Why is a "," necessary in the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `? Extract` a look to understand indexing in R. Here are some hints for how to understand what the object you're looking at is structured:

```
> class(installed.packages())
[1] "matrix"
> dim(installed.packages())
[1] 173  16
> str(installed.packages())
 chr [1:173, 1:16] "aws.s3" "aws.signature" "BH" "bit" "bit64" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:173] "aws.s3" "aws.signature" "BH" "bit" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:16] "Package" "LibPath" "Version" "Priority" ...
```

So, what that tells us is that the object is a matrix, with 173 rows and 16 columns.

- To extract from a matrix, you use notation like `matrix[rows, columns]`.
- To get all rows but only some columns, you can shortcut that to `matrix[, columns]`.
- To get all columns but some rows, you can shortcut that to `matrix[rows,]`

You're probably expecting that the object is a data.frame instead. A data.frame allows various other forms of indexing/extraction with which you might be more familiar:

```
> str(mtcars["mpg"])
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
> str(mtcars[["mpg"]])
 num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
> str(mtcars[, "mpg"])
 num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
> str(mtcars$mpg)
 num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The contents of `installed.packages()` have columns and rows and in subsetting `[a, b]`, `a` are rows and `b` are columns. You're asking for the columns named 'package' and 'version', so you need to tell it to look at columns for those names.

More guidance here: http://statmethods.net/management/subset.html and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html.

Comment: That's not correct, entirely.
`> is.data.frame(installed.packages())
[1] FALSE
> is.array(installed.packages())
[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

For future references, if you want to know which exact GitHub commit is used for a GitHub package:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
package_info("<package_name>")
```